# Netty and MongoDB async callback not working together

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous, netty

I have a simple Netty test server that I would like to query a mongo database and return the result. I've setup the simple hello world tutorial from the Netty repository here: https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/helloworld

I've modified the simple tutorial to add an asynchronous MongoDB call, which returns the same "hello world" string as the example, but after my modification the HTTP call never completes.

Original Method:

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        HttpRequest req = (HttpRequest) msg;

        boolean keepAlive = HttpHeaders.isKeepAlive(req);
        FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(CONTENT));
        response.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
        response.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());

        if (!keepAlive) {
            ctx.write(response).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        } else {
            response.headers().set(CONNECTION, Values.KEEP_ALIVE);
            ctx.write(response);
        }
    }
}
```

After My Change:

```
private final MongoCollection<Document> collection = ...

public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        final HttpRequest req = (HttpRequest) msg;

        collection.find(Filters.eq("_id", new ObjectId("..."))).first(new SingleResultCallback<Document>() {

            public void onResult(Document document, Throwable throwable) {
                boolean keepAlive = HttpUtil.isKeepAlive(req);
                FullHttpResponse response = ...
                (SAME CODE AS ABOVE)
        });
    }
}
```

I can see it's hitting my code, but the response never gets sent to the client. How do I make an async call in the ServerHandler method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to also call `flush()` or change `write(...)` to `writeAndFlush(...)` to ensure the content is really flushed to the socket.